# Annotation Published to my ArcGIS Server is being displayed as a point

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api, annotation

Annotation Published to my ArcGIS Server is being displayed as a point when I build my application with ArcGIS Viewer for Silverlight. How do I get the annotation to display as text and not a point feature?